# Incomplete Stories for the Sprint

Tags: azure-devops

As the ScrumMaster, I am interested in a report that would show me which stories did not complete during the sprint.  While I track this manually outside of the tool, I was curious if there is an easier way?

For instance, in Jira, once a sprint ends, you can see the "incomplete stories" in a sprint report.  Is there something similar for VSTS that would easily allow me to pull stories that were originally forecasted for the sprint, but were not closed by the end date of the sprint?

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t care when the stories complete (change state to close), you can create a query to retrieve all story work items with state (close) and sprint (past sprint).

If the stories must be closed in the sprint time period (e.g. some stories are closed, but closed beyond the sprint time period), there isn’t the way to do it in VSTS, you need to track this manually or programmatically (can build an VSTS extension).